# How to use WebRTC + Pubnub Api for video chat client in Native android app

Tags: android, server, webrtc, pubnub, videochat

i am working on one android application with the functionality of p2p video chat just like Skype. while researching on google, i got some libraries but not getting anything for android native.

i decided to go with WebRTC with the use of PubNub api. how can i create a video chat native android client with the use of there libraries?

i found one code for native video chat client,

https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC

this demo application require url with IP:PORT so i have one confusion about that how the server will be?

can anyone help me?

Comment: Hi Ajay, thank you for asking about Android Native Java Support with WebRTC and PubNub.  You may be interested in checking out XirSys http://xirsys.com/ as an option for your Java Android needs.

Comment: @PubNub : Really Thanx for your help. i have registered with xirsys. and followed all steps as per guide suggest. and got "Sucsess" output. how can i use this detail in Android RTC app?

Comment: @PubNub : but how can i integrate xirsys api in Android native app for video chat? can i use https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC ?

Answer (score 2):

as I understand you need some signaling server which allows to detect peers, exchange session descriptions to setup media ports; and helps share everything used for initial handshake. You can find more information here: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/WebRTC-Signaling-Concepts.html. There a lot of open source implementations e.g. https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

@Alexey Osminin and @Pubnub are right: you need a signal protocol service ([PubNub](http://realtimeweekly.co/android-webrtc-tutorial-pubnub/)) and you need a hosted WebRTC solution for the audio/video streams.

Your best bet is to start with this awesome blog, [BUILDING AN ANDROID WEBRTC VIDEO CHAT APP, by Kevin Gleason](http://realtimeweekly.co/android-webrtc-tutorial-pubnub/) who is the one that did the [AndroidRTC and WebRTC research for PubNub](https://github.com/pubnub/AndroidRTC) as an intern.

## PubNub & WebRTC

There is a lot of confusion around what [PubNub offers in the WebRTC arena and we have compiled everything you need to know into a single knowledge base article](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/252/does-pubnub-support-webrtc-and-video-chat).

Comment: I edited above adding link to AndroidRTC example in github. https://github.com/pubnub/AndroidRTC

Comment: Error:Artifact 'com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:0.13.2:builder-test-api.jar' not found.

Comment: Above error is there after adding your project into android studio.