# WebRTC and screen sharing using PubNub's API?

Tags: video-streaming, chat, webrtc, pubnub, screensharing

I am using PubNub's WebRTC API for video and audio conversations which works like a charm. Next I would like to add screen sharing to my application, but I can't find any useful info inside their documentation, in turn they have the option mentioned in several places.

the code I use right now:

```
var phone = window.phone = PHONE({
            number        :  $('#user_email').text() || "Anonymous", // listen on username line else Anonymous
            publish_key   : 'pub-xxx',
            subscribe_key : 'sub-xxx',
        }); 

        phone.ready(function(){ 
            $('#vid-box').show();
            $('#video-switch').addClass('switch-on');

            });

        phone.receive(function(session){
            session.connected(function(session) { 
            video_out.appendChild(session.video); 
            });

            session.ended(function(session) {
                 video_out.innerHTML='';
                  });
        });



    function startVideo(){
        if (!window.phone) {
             alert("Login First!");
             return false;

        } else {
             phone.dial( $('#other_side').text('ON') );
             $('#cam-button-text').text('Stop Video');
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please refer to this SO thread for details and let me know if you still have further questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740230/how-to-use-webrtc-pubnub-api-for-video-chat-client-in-native-android-app

Comment: And this Codoodler demo app might be a more appropriate resource for what you are asking: https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-09-03-multiuser-draw-html5-canvas-tutorial/

Comment: @CraigConover thank you so much, using the Codedoodler demo, I can now successfully share a stream that I get via webkitGetUserMedia(); One more question, Is there a way I could add a "phone number", like in the video call example so I can share the stream between specific users only? Ps, please add your comment as an answer.

Comment: doesn't the WebRTC demo @ http://webrtc.co provide the details you need to add the phone number to connect two users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to SO thread [How to use WebRTC + Pubnub Api for video chat client in Native android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740230/how-to-use-webrtc-pubnub-api-for-video-chat-client-in-native-android-app)

And also, this PubNub demo/tutorial, [Doodle with Strangers! Multi-User HTML5 Canvas in 4 Steps](http://pubnub.com/blog/2014-09-03-multiuser-draw-html5-canvas-tutorial) might be a more appropriate resource for what you are asking.