# FireBase - maintain/guarantee data consistency

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-security, consistency

I'm trying to understand what is the right approach for this following scenario :

**Multiplayer game,each game structured `only` with two players. Each game/match will be completely randomized**

Lets assume 5 users "logs" the same time into my app, each one of them "searching" for a match. Each user hold a property named `opponent` which equal the the opponent `uniqueID`(initial value equal `""`. so far so good.

assuming user 1 matched with user 3. user 1 will update his own `oppoent` value to user 3 `uniqueID` **and will do the same to user 3**

**Problem**

1) What if at the same moment, user 2 tried to to the same to user 3?
2) What if at the same moment, user 3 tried to do so to user 4?

**Main Point**

Is it possible to "lock" a user values? or freeze them once they changed? Am i going in the wrong approach?

I was thinking using `Security Rules` and `Validation` in order to create consistency but i just may picked the wrong tech(FireBase). Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

Security rules i have tried, which still for some reason enable a third device change "already changed opponent" value.

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
         ".write": true,
      "Users" : 
      {
      "$uid" :  { 
        "opponent" :
        {
          ".write" : "data.val() == 'empty' || data.val() == null",
          ".validate": "data.val() == null || data.val() == 'empty' || newData.parent().parent().child(newData.val())
                    .child('opponent').val() == $uid"
        }
        ,".indexOn": "state"
      }
      }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can validate many things with [Firebase security rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/).

For example, you can say that an opponent can only be written if there currently is no opponent for the user:

```
"users": {
  "$uid": {
    "opponent: {
      ".write": "!data.exists()"
    }
  }
}
```

With this and the following operations:

```
ref.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('opponent').set('uid:1234');
ref.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('opponent').set('uid:2345');
```

The second `set()` operation will fail, because the `opponent` property already has a value at that point.

You can expand that to also validate that the opponents must refer to each other:

```
"users": {
  "$uid": {
    "opponent: {
      ".write": "!data.exists()"
      ".validate": "newData.parent().parent().child(newData.val())
                    .child('opponent').val() == $uid"
    }
  }
}
```

1. From the `opponent` that is being written, we go up two levels back to `users`: `newData.parent().parent()`.
2. Then we go down into the opponent's node: `child(newData.val())`.
3. And we then validate that the opponent's `opponent` property matches our uid: `child('opponent').val() == $uid`.

Now both of the write operations from above will fail, because they're only setting the opponent one at a time. To fix this, you'll need to perform a so-called [multi-location update](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-09-24-atomic-writes-and-more.html):

```
var updates = {};
updates['users/'+auth.uid+'/opponent'] = 'uid:1234';
updates['users/uid:1234/opponent'] = auth.uid;
ref.update(updates);
```

We're now sending a single `update()` command to the Firebase server that writes the uids to both opponents. This will satisfy the security rule.

A few notes:

- these are just some examples to get you started. While they should work, you'll need to write your own rules that meet your security needs.
- these rules just handle writing of opponents. You'll probably also want to testing what happens when the game is over and you need to *clear* the opponents.

Comment: Thank you Frank! I was already went to that direction but clearly you show'ed me the correct path! A few questions(if it's okay) - 1. Does the JavaScript syntax? if so, all the actions you've made possible at iOS sdk as well?

Comment: Yup. I indeed showed JavaScript (partially because it's the one I'm most fluent with, partially because I didn't notice you tagged for iOS). And also a yup on the second one: all these operations are available for iOS as well. The `set()` maps to `setValue` in ObjectiveC, while `update()` maps to `updateChildValues `.

Comment: "You can expand that to also validate that the opponents must refer to each other:". Can you please explain the "validate" that you have made after this quote? "newData.parent().parent().child(newData.val())
                    .child('opponent').val() == auth.uid" ||||| I assume that auth.id is the second uid(I'm using code-generated values so i can keep track of the same user, instead of annonunymous login). I haven't fully understand the newData.parent().parent()

Comment: Got it! Awesome! Thank you Frank! FireBase is completely amazing, I have 1 last question, actually is the one i am most concern about. Like the OP says, if 5 users logs at the same time, and our method works, is it possible "retry" and search for another user to match too? I guess that if the "write/update" operation fails it will get a callback(with an error)? + Does this(by this i mean what you wrote above) suppose to guarantee that there will be no duplication? conflicts? or there is a still lack or validation? (in case what i have presented above is the real scenario)?

Comment: And another small thing, for the first "write" (when he just registered), It will deny me from writing the first value(because the validation), dosent it? In case i'm using "setValue" for this first time, does newData equal data? or there is no data, and it will reffer only to the newData?

Comment: And Thank you Frank! you patience is complete gold.

Comment: All writes to your database happen sequentially. So you can verify that none of the two opponents currently has an opponent in the `.write` rule. Alternatively you can [run a transaction](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/saving-data.html#section-transactions) on the entire `users` node and simply set both opponents that way. That is easier, but reduces scalability.

Comment: I see, I guess you are right. For some reason it dosent let me setValue as for the first time. Would you mean if i edit the post with the value i'm adding?

Comment: Hey Frank. I figured most of the things out. the problem is that when i update two users like we have said, and than a third device logs in, he again changes one of the devices property(what i was thinking we got covered), I have changed the security codes a bit because i couldn't write the initial value. I edited the orginal post

Comment: So i changed the "validated" final if to  "data.val() == null || data.val() == 'empty' || newData.parent().parent().child(newData.val())
                    .child('opponent').val() == **empty** instead of **$uid**"    And now it's seems to work, i think we have made this check wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You might also look at the [transaction operation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/saving-data.html#section-transactions).

Firebase transactions make sure that the current set of data you are acting on is really what is in the database, guaranteeing that you are updating data that is in the right condition.  The docs indicate that this is the recommended way to avoid race conditions such as you describe.

Something like this (in IOS, and warning - not tested):

```
NSString* user1Key = @"-JRHTHaIs-jNPLXOQivY";
NSString* user2Key = @"-NFHUaIs-kNPLJDHuvY";

Firebase *user1Ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl: @"https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com.users/-JRHTHaIs-jNPLXOQivY/opponent"];
Firebase *user2Ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl: @"https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com.users/-NFHUaIs-kNPLJDHuvY/opponent"];

//See if the proposed opponent does not yet have a match
[user2Ref runTransactionBlock:^FTransactionResult *(FMutableData *opponent) {
if (opponent.value == [NSNull null]) {
    //They have no match - update with our key and signal success
    [opponent setValue:user1Key];
    return [FTransactionResult successWithValue: opponent];
} else {
    return [FTransactionResult abort];  //They already have an opponent - fail
    //Notify the user that the match didn't happen
   }    
} andCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error, BOOL committed, FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    if (!error && committed) {   
        //The transaction above was committed with no error 
        //Update our record with the other player - we're matched!
        [user1ref setValue:user2Key];

        //Do whatever notification you want
    } else {
       //Notify that the matchup failed 
    }

}];
```

Comment: hey Giff. Thank you for your respond. Actually i used multi-path update and it *seems*(small scale) to work fine. Can you please elaborate about the difference between updating this path using UpdateChilds(counting on Security & Validation) from this method? Another question, Does Transaction uses the Security Rules as well as updateChild?

Comment: A transaction operation is guaranteed to be synced with what your code is looking at - regular updates (including multi-path updates) don't have that guarantee. This may be overkill for you - it is unlikely that the multi path update/ security rules wouldn't handle things - technically conceivable that both conflicting write operations at the exact same time would pass the security rule and then each update, but would be unlikely.  The transaction checks the data explicitly just before commit.   Included it here in case someone read this with data that many users update very frequently,

Comment: All write operations - `set()`, (multi-path) `update()` and `transaction()` - are subject tot he `.write` and `.validate` rules. There is no way to bypass them. The difference between `transaction()` and the others is that it has access to the current value of the data that it updates and can determine the new value based on that. The `.write` and `.validate` security rules also have access to the current and new data, but cannot change the new data based on the current value.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen & Giff Thank you very much for your help. I'm having small issue with "update", when having two different requests running almost at the same time(worst scenario case), using transaction suppose to solve this problem?

Comment: @rio - Yes.  Make sure you understand the pattern of the transaction operation - https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/saving-data.html#section-transactions